# ionic framework 2.0 push notifications on event not found

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am really struggling to add push notification support to my Ionic application. My current issue is related to the [documentation](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#background-notifications), which states that I need to add a cordova push plugin (which I have) and then to add the following event handler:

```
this.push.on('notification', function (data) {
    // do something with the push data
    // then call finish to let the OS know we are done
    push.finish(function () {
        console.log("processing of push data is finished");
    }, function () {
        console.log("something went wrong with push.finish for ID = " + data.additionalData.notId)
    }, data.additionalData.notId);
});
```

However, I am getting an `on` property not found the error. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. The browser outputs that `this.push.on` is not a function. Probably has to do with the browser not supporting `Push` and it's native capabilities.

However, using it in your mobile applicationw ill work just fine. If you want to make the error go away because it is confusing you could check on which OS the user currently is or check if he has cordova.

This can be done by wrapping your `push.on` in a `if(this.platform.is('cordova')){}` or `if(platform.is('cordova'))` (not sure about the `this.`) Source: [How to detect if I am in browser (local development) in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470325/how-to-detect-if-i-am-in-browser-local-development-in-ionic-2)

Comment: using this.push.plugin.on seemed to fix it for me in the end!

Comment: Ah well I use `this.push.on` works as well, just the annoying error in console :) cool that by adding `.plugin` it works