# How to bypass 'Cordova is not defined' and continue using Ionic Lab

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way to bypass the 'Cordova is not defined' error?

I use it just in one small function on my page and I wish I could continue testing the rest using the Ionic Lab.

Is it possible?

I tried testing every place it got used,but I guess the problem is in

declare var cordova:any;

Comment: Could you please tell us which Cordova plugin are you using in your app? Is just to make the answer as accurate as possible...

Comment: In this case I'm using the cordova-file-transfer plugin

Comment: Your question is not very clear but I believe you want to implement different logic when not on phone.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470325/how-to-detect-if-i-am-in-browser-local-development-in-ionic-2)

Comment: @PhilipBrack That solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific when you ask something please..

Maybe try declaring cordova as object:

`if (!cordova) { 
   cordova = {};
}`

Comment: What other info do you need?

I tried that in ionViewDidLoad and didn't work.

Also tried let cordovaFileDir = cordova ? cordova.file.dataDirectory : null; instead of using directly codorva.file and didn't work also.

Comment: provide code where you are encountering the error please..

Comment: pathForImage(img) {
    if (img === null) {
      return '';
    } else {
      let cordovaFileDir = cordova ? cordova.file.dataDirectory : null;
      return cordovaFileDir + img;
    }
  }

Only this code is not called when entering the page, it is in a specific function