# Check if device's running cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, angularfire

I have ready web application and i've made an android app ,using Cordova, from it, it works good, but when i do this:

```
 if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
      return this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(res => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['main-layout']);
          });
        }).catch(error => {
          window.alert(error);
        });
 } else {
   return this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
 }
```

I expect that on android app `else` will be reached, but it did not.

So, how can i check whether app is running on android (cordova) or on desktop in Angular?

I've tried this [How to detect if I am in browser (local development) in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470325/how-to-detect-if-i-am-in-browser-local-development-in-ionic-2), but it did not help me.

I'm using cordova 9, angular 10.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "in desktop", you want to say in a Navigator? if yes, I updated recently my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602342/angular-6-cordova-how-to-convert-current-angular-project-to-cordova-based-pr/52603564#52603564. My idea is has a little "script" in the .html page `<script>window.isInCordova=true</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

This is a reference for getting device platform for cordova, it could be adding using cmd:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

***Properties:***

- device.cordova
- device.model
- device.platform
- device.uuid
- device.version
- device.manufacturer
- device.isVirtual
- device.serial

You could use device.platform to achieve what you need for example:

```
if (device.platform === 'iOS') {}
if (device.platform === 'browser') {}
if (device.platform === 'Android') {}
```

And tou could see full documentation in link above to see more things or other supported platforms

Comment: yeah, i've tried this, i wrote `(<any>device).platform === "browser"` in Angular, but angular throws an error , how check for device.platform in angular PageComponent file ?

Comment: device is decalred in constructor private device: Device, another way is to do let win = window as any;  and then add win.platform, this will give you same result as above

Comment: Thank you, the solution i've found was `((<any>window)._cordovaNative)`, i've output all window global objects and there was not a cordova but _cordovaNative )